# bash pipelining, read the previous output

Tags: bash

lets say I want to use the output that I got through a pipe and use it in Bash, how would I be doing that ?

For example,

```
head -6 filename.txt | tail -3 "last pipe's output"
```

The idea is to get lines 4, 5 and 6 from the file (yes I know there are better ways I just want to understand how to refer to the pipe's previous output)

Is there a saved word/symbol for using the previous pipe's output?

Comment: A pipeline feeds standard output to standard input. You don't need to "refer" to it at all for commands (like `tail`) that can operate on standard input.

Comment: thank you ! didn't realise its that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the base system utilities will use standard input (stdin) in the absence of an explicit filename.  In a pipeline, the output from the process on the left hand side of the pipe is tied to the standard input of the process on the right hand side of the pipe.

```
head -6 filename.txt | tail -3
```